# Building a 'flexible/responsive' select/option field for a form

Tags: javascript, html-select

I am trying to build a complex form with "flexible" select/option elements for ease-of-use that should only reveal themselves depending on the user's selection. In other words, if a user selects a certain option in one `<select>` group, then a new set of options should reveal themselves in a second `<select>` group. My situation is a *bit* more complex than this, but this is a summary of its behavior.

However, I want a nicer interface than what I currently have; namely, I want the form to be supported and ideally uniform across browsers.

---

I have one particular `<select>` element (let's call this element 'selectA') which has a list of various options, namely 'optionA-1', 'optionA-2', and 'optionA-3'.

I have another `<select>` element, called 'selectB', which should only reveal itself when 'optionA-1' or 'optionA-3' is selected. 'selectB' also has four other options, poignantly named 'optionB-1', 'optionB-2', 'optionB-3', and of course 'optionB-4'.

Having 'selectB' disappear and reappear at will is routine --- just a little bit of JS and, presto, a "magically" responsive form!

Here's the challenge, though: **'optionB-3' and 'option-B-4' should only be visible if 'optionA-3' is selected; otherwise, they should not be displayed.**

It's not so much that I can't do this, but I want a design that is crisp (i.e., no excessive spaces where none is needed) and isn't *too* dependent on JavaScript (since users can enable or disable it at will and I don't want the core functionality to break).

Here is *roughly* the structure of the form, as-is:

```html
<form>
    <select name='selectA' id='selectA' onchange='showSelectB()'>
        <option value='DEFAULT-A'>---Choose one---</option>
        <option value='optionA-1'>OptionA-1</option>
        <option value='optionA-2'>OptionA-2</option>
        <option value='optionA-3'>OptionA-3</option>
    </select>

    <select name='selectB' id='selectB'>
        <option value='DEFAULT-B'>---Choose another one---</option>
        <option value='optionB-1'>OptionB-1</option>
        <option value='optionB-2'>OptionB-2</option>
        <option class='hideable' value='optionB-3'>OptionB-3</option>
        <option class='hideable' value='optionB-4'>OptionB-4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Seems pretty simple, right? Okay, now for the JavaScript function to make 'selectB' more 'flexible/responsive' (it is implied that this is in the same file in a `<script>` element):

```
function showSelectB()
{
    var selectABox = document.getElementById("selectA");
    var selectedValue = selectABox.options[selectABox.selectedIndex].value;
    var selectBBox = document.getElementById("selectB");

    if(selectedValue == "optionA-1" || selectedValue == "optionA-3")
    {
        selectBBox.style.display = ""; //Ta-da!

        var options = document.getElementsByClassName("hideable");
        var length = options.length;

        if(selectedValue == 'optionA-3')
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                options[i].style.display = ""; //Now you see me...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                options[i].style.display = "none"; //...Now you don't
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        selectBBox.style.display = "none"; //Disappear!
    }
}

//I was being lazy here
document.getElementById("selectB").style.display = "none";
```

(Now, I know jQuery syntax is cleaner, but I prefer good-ol' JavaScript in this case.)

If you test this, you'll see it works fine; options come-and-go as expected... except for one caveat:

- When 'optionA-1' is selected in 'selectA', 'selectB' gets these gad-awful spaces left behind when options B-3 and B-4 no longer display (at least, they do so on my version of Microsoft Edge, which I found quite strange since that's more like how the `visibility` attribute should work); to me, it looks quite ugly.

A substitute I tried for this JavaScript code was to consider the 'hideable' options as child nodes of 'selectB' and appending or removing them whenever 'optionA-3' was selected or 'un-selected', but it seemed horribly messy and was error-prone (namely, it would add too many options if I selected 'optionA-3' right out of the gate). I probably neglected an if or else condition somewhere, but it just failed to work in a significant amount of my test runs.

I was wondering if, perhaps, there is a third alternative that keeps the form responsive, yet doesn't get muddled with these inconsistencies that float about in 'selectB' (at least, on Microsoft Edge and IE).

---

**EDIT:** Here is a workable snippet, as requested.

```js
function showSelectB()
{
    var selectABox = document.getElementById("selectA");
    var selectedValue = selectABox.options[selectABox.selectedIndex].value;
    var selectBBox = document.getElementById("selectB");

    if(selectedValue == "optionA-1" || selectedValue == "optionA-3")
    {
        selectBBox.style.display = ""; //Ta-da!

        var options = document.getElementsByClassName("hideable");
        var length = options.length;
        
        if(selectedValue == 'optionA-3')
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                options[i].style.display = ""; //Now you see me...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                options[i].style.display = "none"; //...Now you don't
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        selectBBox.style.display = "none"; //Disappear!
    }
}

//I was being lazy here
document.getElementById("selectB").style.display = "none";
```

```html
<form>
    <select name='selectA' id='selectA' onchange='showSelectB()'>
        <option value='DEFAULT-A'>---Choose one---</option>
        <option value='optionA-1'>OptionA-1</option>
        <option value='optionA-2'>OptionA-2</option>
        <option value='optionA-3'>OptionA-3</option>
    </select>

    <select name='selectB' id='selectB'>
        <option value='DEFAULT-B'>---Choose another one---</option>
        <option value='optionB-1'>OptionB-1</option>
        <option value='optionB-2'>OptionB-2</option>
        <option class='hideable' value='optionB-3'>OptionB-3</option>
        <option class='hideable' value='optionB-4'>OptionB-4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Interestingly enough, I didn't test this well enough across browsers; I now notice that it works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but sadly not Microsoft Edge (and IE downright fails altogether). So, clearly this is a cross-browser issue. The problem is, where does this 'cross-browser' issue stem from?

Comment: So, the term "responsive" is horribly overloaded in today's web design/development landscape, and it's a bit unclear what you're talking about when you talk about "excessive spaces". What would be great is if you could use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create an example here on Stack Overflow that we can run and see exactly what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add the `hidden` attribute, instead of changing the visibility of the component.

So this line:

```
options[i].style.display = ""; //Now you see me...
```

Would become this

```
options[i].removeAttribute("hidden"); //Now you see me...
```

---

And this line:

```
options[i].style.display = "none"; //...Now you don't
```

Would become this

```
options[i].setAttribute("hidden", ""); //Now you don't
```

#### References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

#### Browser Compatibility:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden#Browser_compatibility

Comment: While this _is_ an alternate solution to changing the display, there's still two problems: 1) I think you have them backwards; `options[i].removeAttribute("hidden")` reveals the text, while `options[i].setAttribute("hidden", "")` hides it, and 2) it still shows a empty space in 'selectB' on Edge, while on Firefox and Chrome it does not.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I did get them backward, sorry! (Just updated the answer) And I was assuming that would work fine on Edge because of the Browser compatibility :(

Comment: I think why the browser compatibility issue with Edge remains is not because of the `hidden` attribute, but instead because of the JavaScript methods `removeAttribute()` and `setAttribute()`; e.g., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute#Browser_compatibility and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#Browser_compatibility